# Publicly available InfoPath form connecting to Access db in a restricted location

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have searched the forums on this site many times to get help but this is the first time I am posting, so, Hi everyone. 
Hopefully someone has an answer to my question. I have an InfoPath 2010 form which is available to everyone to use, hosted on SharePoint that needs to connect to an Access 2010 database which is stored in a restricted drive location. The form needs to be accessible to all staff but due to the sensitivity of the data being submitted, the database must remain restricted. Also, the form needs to be able to query the database for the secondary data connections. Please note that using SharePoint lists in not an option available to the team that will be maintaining the data submitted. Does anyone know of a way to enable the form to be able to connect to the database to query & submit without assigning access to the restricted folder to all staff. I have been told it may be possible to "assign" a system account to the form which will have access to the restricted folder but I also need to ensure the form can populate the users data into certain fields ,such as USER() & email address. I would classify myself as a beginner to intermediate InfoPath user. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. Andrew

Comment: Try it yourself first and when you are stuck then ask your problem here.

Comment: Hi Nilambar. I am able to use the form to query & submit to the database as I have access to the restricted folder but my colleague who does not is unable to open the form properly. He gets the "Some External data was not retrieved." error message. Any possible suggestions would be greatly appreciated.